# Why insert post function do not set the modified author without administrator panel?

Tags: front-end, wp-insert-post

I am have a front-end new post and edit post forms.

- I'll using the `<?php wp_insert_post( $post ); ?>`

Everything is all right here.

If any **editor** or **admin** modified any author posts on front-end: `<?php the_modified_author(); ?>` not working. But modified on `/wp-admin` administrator panel working it.

> I want to update `<?php the_modified_author(); ?>` on my function! But
>   how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_modified_author()` displays the name of the user whose ID has been stored in the `_edit_last` post meta field.

If you want to update the ID after another user has updated the post, you can use something like `update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_edit_last', get_current_user_id() );`. Then the new user's name will be displayed when using `the_modified_author()`.

Replace `get_current_user_id()` with a custom user ID if it's not the current user who's updating the post.

Comment: Thanks @swissspidy it work now.
But I dont understand, Before you, If update post (front-end) I don't set the modified author! How work in the panel? And why not work front-end :)

Comment: In the admin area, other functions are used in addition to `wp_insert_post()`, which all call `update_post_meta()` manually. For example `wp_restore_post_revision()` and — most notably — `edit_post()`. I guess the reason is that `wp_insert_post()` is usually used for lots of other (automated) stuff not involving any users. So it doesn't make sense to update the user inside `wp_insert_post()` because the information might be wrong. Plus, you don't want that information stored for _every_ post type. Thus, it needs to be done this way.